# How to resize only image width using scrapy?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, scrapy

Using scrapy I can resize an image and keep its aspect ratio.
http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/images.html#std:setting-IMAGES_THUMBS

```
IMAGES_THUMBS = {
    'small': (50, 50),
    'big': (270, 270), 
}
```

what I want is only re sizing the image width and keeping the image height as it is.
does anyone know how to do this ?

NOTE: I'm using scrapy to upload the images to amazon s3, so I don't have the option of resizing them locally.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own [Images pipeline](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/images.html#module-scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images). In the `item_completed` method, you can open all the downloaded images and resize them using [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/index.htm). Scrapy already uses PIL for its imaging pipelines.

Here is a tentative example. (I don't use Scrapy.)

```
from scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images import ImagesPipeline
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from scrapy.http import Request

from PIL import Image

class MyImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        for image_url in item['image_urls']:
            yield Request(image_url)

    def item_completed(self, results, item, info):
        for result, image_info in results:
            if result:
                path = image_info['path']
                img = Image.open(path)
                # here is where you do your resizing - this method overwrites the
                # original image you will need to create a copy if you want to keep
                # the original.
                img = img.resize((100, 72))
                img.save(path)
        return item
```

You can see what Scrapy does in its default Image pipeline: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/pipeline/images.py#L283. And below line 300 you can read the default implementations for these two methods.

Comment: I'm using scrapy to upload the images to amazon s3, so I don't have the option of resizing them locally.

Comment: An image is just bytes. You can modify it in memory before sending it to amazon S3.